# Killing multiple instances of the script from the script itself

Tags: shell-script, kill, function

I've couple instances of script.sh running in parallel, doing the same thing, running in background.

I'm trying to use a function to kill all the current running scripts when executed.

So, for example, ./script.sh -start will start the script (which I can run few in parallel) and when I execute ./script.sh -kill will kill all instances of the script.

```
f() {
    procName=`basename $0`
    pidsToKill=`ps -ef | grep $procName | grep -v grep | awk '{ print $2 }'`
    if [[ $pidsToKill ]]; then
        for i in $pidsToKill; do
            kill -9 $i
        done
        echo "Killed running scripts."
    else
        echo "No opened scripts to kill"
    fi
}
```

For some reason, sometimes it kill couple of the scripts and sometimes returns an error.

I've figured a way to solve this, but I want to understand why this one doesn't work. Any ideas?

Comment: [You really shouldn't do that.](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ProcessManagement)

Comment: Why? I know it might not be the best solution, but the script is that simple. I don't need subscripts.

Comment: It's explained in detail on linked page.

Comment: This script also kills itself, `less myprogramname/README`, and other unrelated processes. [Don't do this](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ProcessManagement).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The script may be killing itself. You might try running the for loop inside a separate subshell `( for i in $pidsToKill; do kill -9 $i; done; echo All dead. ) &` and then exit your script.

Comment: Ok gotcha. That make sense. Thank you, and thanks l0b0 too.
Putting the command inside ( ), causing it to run in a subshell?